# Best practice: AmazonS3 url sharing

Tags: amazon-s3, standards, conventions

I planning to keep access to files on AmazonS3 as private. But I would like to share file URL with a limited group of people.

What is recommended way for doing this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just create a [signed, time limited url](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html) and share it with them in whatever way you like.

You could also look at using [AWS Identity and Access Management (IAM)](http://aws.amazon.com/iam/) (currently in Beta) for other ways to control access. But, honestly, querystring authentication is going to be the simplest to implement and should be fine for the majority of use cases.

Comment: "... should be fine for the majority of use cases." can you provide a use case where it may not be useful/appropriate to use query string authentication.